# Masking the URL in a mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Is there any way of doing a mod_rewrite from one domain to another, but keeping the browser URL the same throughout? This is what I want:

User enters something like **bacon.com** and ends up on **example.com/bacon**, but the browser URL always stays as bacon.com?

I basically want to do a mod_rewrite whilst masking the URL. Sorry for the unimaginative example domains, but it's still only 10am... I've checked lots of other answers, but they always usually involve mod_rewrites on the *same* domain. They don't deal with the fact that bacon.com is already a ServerAlias of example.com.

Comment: You can serve the page example.com/bacon in various ways, such as proxying it, but there's a bunch of other issues: which domain gets to get cookies? What is the base URL considered to be for image and CSS requests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can give you three ways of doing this.

### 1 Using virtual hosts

Given that bacon.com is a ServerAlias for example.com, i.e. they're both on the same server, you can do this without using any mod_rewrite at all. Think of it this way: mod_rewrite is at its most basic a way to map URLs to a file system. So what I would do is to simply set up a separate VirtualHost that uses the correct directory as its base.

Here's a brief example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /www/files

  [... all other config you have for example.com]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bacon.com
  DocumentRoot /www/files/bacon

  # To have CSS directly under /www/files/css instead of /www/files/bacon/css
  Alias /css /www/files/css

  [... all other config you have for bacon.com]
</VirtualHost>
```

As you see, this isn't a rewrite; instead you're setting bacon.com up to use the base directory of example.com/bacon as its own DocumentRoot.

### 2 Using mod_rewrite as a proxy

If you do want to use mod_rewrite instead, you can have it use the P flag which will make mod_rewrite act as a proxy. Here's an example:

```
RewriteRule /(.*) http://example.com/bacon/$1 [P]
```

#### Edit in answer to the comment:

Since you want the http://bacon.com/css to be http://example.com/css instead of http://example.com/bacon/css, make a separate rule that goes first and catches that specific URL:

```
RewriteRule /css/(.*) http://example.com/css/$1 [P]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://example.com/bacon/$1 [P]
```

In order to do this, you need to have mod_proxy loaded and enabled. Do however note  that this will reduce performance compared to using mod_proxy directly, as it doesn't handle persistent connections or connection pooling. So if you can't do what you want with VirtualHosts, I'd suggest the third method:

### 3 Using mod_proxy directly

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bacon.com

  ProxyPass http://example.com/bacon
  ProxyPassReverse  http://example.com/bacon
</VirtualHost>
```

For more information about that, see [the mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: +1 for the [P] flag (which works), but now I'm getting no styles. How can I get the mod_rewrite to ignore URLs for css (so bacon.com/css/ should be redirected to example.com/css)

Comment: I'm adding that to the answer, give me a sec...

Comment: Thanks for the [P] flag. Exactly what I was looking for: simple, and just working. :)